# bootstrapでtableの縦線を消して横線のみ表示させたい

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrapでtableの縦線を消して横線だけ表示させたいです。
知ってる方がいれば是非ご教授ください。

Answer (score 1):

以下はBootstrap 3 の基本的なテーブルを[公式のドキュメント](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-example)より引用したものです。

縦線は存在しませんが、これで解決できませんか？

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class=table>
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <th scope=row>1</th> 
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th scope=row>2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td> 
      <td>Thornton</td> 
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <th scope=row>3</th>
      <td>Larry</td> 
      <td>the Bird</td> 
      <td>@twitter</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

(公式のドキュメントのライセンスは CC BY 3.0. なので、これに従って引用しています。)

Comment: おお！できました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: 質問を編集して「現行どういうコードを書いていたのか」も示しておいて貰えるといい質問になるかもしれません。